# Saved Core Data items are visible only after relaunching the app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mpmediaitemcollection, iphonecoredatarecipes

1. RootVC.swift

   ```
   private let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

   private var fetchRecordRequestController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   // Initialize fetch request
   fetchRecordRequestController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRecordRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
   fetchRecordRequestController.delegate = self
   // Fetch data from object
   do {
       try fetchRecordRequestController.performFetch()
   } catch let fetchError as NSError {
       print("(RootVC)fetchError: \(fetchError), \(fetchError.userInfo)")
   }}
   ```
2. AddRuleVC.swift

// Initialize managedObjectContext for creating a new object from the input

```
private var managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

// Method to save the extracted values to CoreData Objects

```
func saveValues() {
```

// Setting up, to save on a private queue

```
let privateManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
privateManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator
```

// Initialize entity description

```
let RuleDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Rule",inManagedObjectContext:privateManagedObjectContext)
let rule = Rule(entity: RuleDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: privateManagedObjectContext)
```

// Perform Block

```
privateManagedObjectContext.performBlock { () -> Void in
```

// Set object values from temporary variables

```
rule.music = musicTemp! as MPMediaItemCollection
    print("musicTemp = \(musicTemp!.count)=========>saveValues")
// Save the object

    do {

    //print(NSStringFromClass((self.rule?.classForCoder)!))

            try rule.managedObjectContext?.save()
        } catch let saveError as NSError {
            print("(AddRuleViewController)saveError: \(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

My RootVC is for fetching the data stored using AddRuleVC. I can save as many rules as I'd want to, but they do not show once the AddRuleVC segues back to the RootVC. They only show up after a relaunch.

Comment: How are you attempting to save this `MPMediaItemCollection`? That class does not conform to `NSCoding`, so what are you doing to try and put it into Core Data?

Comment: As I have an attribute, which is "transformable", I pass `MPMediaItemCollection` to it and save it. It works perfectly, and there are no errors while saving. I can again retrieve the same by typecasting it as `MPMediaItemCollection`, and am able to use it for queuing it up or retrieving metadata for each track by passing it into array of `[MediaItem]`s.

Comment: @TomHarrington, any idea about the error, `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Most likely you're using something that's not a collection (probably an array) where a collection is expected. Can't say more without more details of the code.

Comment: @TomHarrington, I've added more detail. Please let me know if I'm missing anything. Sorry, for probably asking a very trivial question. New to swift!! :-|

Comment: Sorry, I really can't tell.

Comment: No worries, @TomHarrington. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: By the way, just confirmed that `MPMediaItemCollection`, conforms to `NSSecureCoding`. Not sure, if this will help you @TomHarrington, in providing me a way out of the quicksand, that I am into for the past week.

Comment: @TomHarrington, I've modified the information, as I'm facing another problem. And, thanks again, for your help in the earlier issue.